# Problema configurando mi .htaccess

Tags: error404

Estoy casi seguro que tiene que ver con el .htaccess. Buen día, tengo un sitio en el que estoy usando para ocultar el link de ciertas cosas que estoy haciendo en php, y usé este código:

```
 Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```

El problema ahora es que, al visitar por ejemplo www.midominio.com/categoria mi web no me da acceso a esa categoría, me muestra el tipico mensaje de "compra este dominio", etc.

Qué estoy haciendo mal? Gracias por contestar.

Comment: ¿Usas www.midominio.com/categoria para ingresar? porque si tienes tu pagina en local prueba con localhost/categorias o 127.0.0.1/categorias

Comment: Mil disculpas, estuve ausente un par de días por problemas de conexion. Uso la compañia 1and1 para alojar mi sitio. En localhost si funciona perfectamente mi página, solo una vez subida no me muestra nada. Aqui el ejemplo: http://acldesigns.com/productos

Answer (score -1):

posiblemente sea RewriteRule que no lo has declarado bien aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```

Comment: Debes explicar alguna indicación para completar tu respuesta. Respuestas basadas solo en código no son bien recibidas en este sitio. Edita tu respuesta con alguna explicación que aclare tu respuesta, como por ejemplo justificando porqué soluciona el problema.